# Tomcat 6 restrict access to web applications by URL

Tags: tomcat6, security

I have Apache Tomcat 6.0.35(Wndows 2008) with a bunch of application installed.
I have deleted webapps\ROOT*,  renamed my application to ROOT.war, deployed and now I have my application as a root(the following URLs are used in the applications - http:/exampleapp.com/, http:/exampleapp.com/SomePostUri). Port 8080 changed to 80.

How I can forbid access(via HTTP)  to the following applications:

1) Tomcat's Manager application (http:/exampleapp.com/manager/html) - allow access only from localhost.

2) All others installed web applications (e.g. http:/exampleapp.com/docs)  - allow access only from localhost.

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed Apache HTTP and joined it with Tomcat  via mod_jk.
Solved.